# Let $\bar X_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ where $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then find $\lim_{{n\to\infty}} P(\bar X_n=2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of iid random variables having a common density function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
    xe^{-x} & \text{if } x\geq0 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Let $\bar X_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ where $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then find $\lim_{{n\to\infty}} P(\bar X_n=2)$.

**My try**

My first thought as well but I think the problem is deeper than that. I think that as the n tends towards infinity the probability of the the sample mean converging to the population mean is 1. Looking at proving this.

By the Central Limit Theorem the sample mean distribution can be approximated by a Normal distribution with $$\mu = 2,~\sigma = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n}}$$

As $n\to \infty$this becomes a delta function centered at $2$

Comment: *Hint.* $P(\bar X_n=2)=P\bigl(\sqrt n(\bar X_n-2)=0\bigr)\le P\bigl(\sqrt n|\bar X_n-2|\le\varepsilon\bigr)$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this. $\overline{X}_n$ is a continuous random variable so $P(\overline{X}_n = a) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\overline{X}_n = 2)= \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$$